# about the lesson 4 create FundMe.sol

Tags: remix

ParserError: Expected primary expression.
--> contracts/FundMe.sol:24:10:
|
24 |         (,int price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
|          ^

how to solve this problem? i follow this video step by step to do it, but i don't know what step i got wrong.

```
function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    // ABI
    // Address 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306)
    (,int price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    // ETH in terms of USD
    // 3000.00000000
    return uint256(price * 1e10); 1**10 == 10000000000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the semicolon after this line

```
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
```

try to use https://remix.ethereum.org/ online tool which makes it easier to build smart contracts

also you have to add semicolon after

```
return uint256(price * 1e10); 1**10 == 10000000000
```